# Import Google My Maps into Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using [my maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) to display a map on my site, however I don't want to just embed this in an Android app. I'd rather be able to use an API to pull all the information and then use it in my app to display it on the native map and then make them searchable. How can I get the data from My Maps into my app?

I also noticed that the Search Engine API that use to provide this is deprecated and will be discontinued next year but I was wondering if there was a work around. I saw some people suggest fusion tables, but will that pull data from MyMaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can [export](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en) your map as a KML and add [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) to your android application.

Google Maps for mobile supports this subset of KML elements:

- Placemarks with  elements
- Points
- Icons
- Folders
- HTML in the
   element (text formatting, images, lists, tables, and
  other HTML elements)
- KMZ (compressed KML, including attached images)
- LineStrings and Polygons
- Styles for polylines and polygons, including
  color, fill, and opacity

Comment: Yes, but if I import the KML it then becomes static and isn't updated when the map is online correct?